# DynamoDB Set order

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

From DynamoDB docs:

> An attribute of type String Set. For example:
>
> "SS": ["Giraffe", "Hippo" ,"Zebra"]
>
> Type: Array of strings
>
> Required: No

This is all I could find. I did some testing but that's clearly not enough for production environments and I would like to get a confirmation/confutation from people who have actually worked with these Sets.

Do DynamoDB Sets maintain insertion order? Can I count on that fact & build logic around that?

Im mainly interested in `String Set` but it probably applies to all of them (`String`, `Number`, `Binary`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html). SET data type doesn't preserve the order.

> **SET** :  The order of the values within a set are not preserved;
>   therefore, your applications must not rely on any particular order of
>   elements within the set.
>
> **LIST** - A list type attribute can store an ordered collection of values

[Similar discussion on AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=487246)